# How to convert utf8 into binary

Tags: utf-8, binary

Recently I am studying about binary code, and I want to know how do I convert text that has been encoded by UTF-8 and then into binary?

Comment: "text that has been encoded by UTF-8 " is a sequence of bytes. "into binary" do you mean to display the bits of a byte as 8 text digits?

Comment: I have this question too. Please assume that the UTF-8 was embedded in - for instance XML file, and there is a need to convert it back to it's binary form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using the command-line tool `iconv`.

For example:

```
$ iconv option
$ iconv options -f from-encoding -t to-encoding inputfile(s) -o outputfile
```

Here is a online tutorial that might be of help:

https://www.tecmint.com/convert-files-to-utf-8-encoding-in-linux/

Comment: This does NOT answer the above question. I have the PDF file which was embedded into XML and is encoded as UTF-8. I need to convert it back to pure binary form. NOT text like "01000101" but stream of bytes.

Comment: @Damago the original question is unclear and cannot be answered without more information. What does 'binary' mean in the context of the question? To get an answer to your specific question you'll get a better response if you create a new question that addresses your specific needs.